# Do I need a letter of recommendation from my employer to vouch for the projects I worked on with them when applying to master's programs in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, recommendation-letter

I wish to apply for a master's in CS in the United States as an international student.  It has been quite some time since I graduated and I currently work as a software developer.

While I have worked on several projects in work, would it be necessary for it to be verified through a professional letter of recommendation (LOR)? I am unable to get a professional LOR from my current employer but I can get it from my past employers. Further, would it be necessary to share a link to my Github repository in my academic resume? I don't have a strong Github profile right now.

Comment: Please ask only one question.  You should get one or more letters from current or recent supervisors.  The letters should be written in the detailed American style for best results.  However, some US masters programs are not selective and won't care.

Comment: It is only _necessary_ if it is asked for in the application instructions, and I doubt it will be, but you should read the instructions anyway.